# Challenge #375 of r/dailyprogrammer - Print a new number by adding one to each of its digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I don't know a lot of programming, but I'm trying to learn all I know in C++ now in Python so I've decided to try those easy challenges they propose on reddit. This was pretty easy in C++ for me, but I'm struggling in Python since arrays work differently.

So this is my try at the problem:

```
x=(input("Give me the number: "))
arr=[]
for i in range (0,len(x)):
    a=int(x[i])+1
    arr.append(a)
for i in range (0,len(arr)):
    print (arr[i])
```

It gets the number and adds one to each of it's digits, but when I run it the result, for example for 50:
6

1

Instead of 61. How can I change that?

Original problem: A number is input in computer then a new no should get printed by adding one to each of its digit. If you encounter a 9, insert a 10 (don't carry over, just shift things around).

For example, 998 becomes 10109.

Comment: @DeepSpace  now it's poste

Comment: @meowgoesthedog now it's posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example it is

```
for i in range (0,len(arr)):
    print (arr[i], end = "")
    #                ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to get an integer back, and feel like writing an obscure one-liner:

```
print(int(''.join(map(lambda d: str(int(d) + 1), input("Give me the number: ")))))
```